# Velodyne Lidar decoding in real time

Tags: cloud, processing, point, point-cloud-library, lidar

I am new to LiDAR data processing. 
My goal is to convert the raw Velodyne packet(UDP packet) into XYZ format for visualization in unity. 
I found some libraries(pypcl), but it is not applied in real-time. 
Theoretically, it should be possible to decode each packet and deliver decoded data to virtual reality application(unity). But it is not easy to implement it from the scratch.

Can you please give me an advice on this issue?
I have searched for several weeks, but I could not find a proper method.

Best regards
Seongsu

Answer (score 0):

velodyne_pointcloud package has an [API](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/velodyne_pointcloud/html/classvelodyne__rawdata_1_1RawData.html) which allows you to convert a packet to a pointcloud.

You can read more about this discussion [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/261061/converting-velodyne-packets-to-pointcloud/).